# Sitecore Page Editor Add New Page Inline

Tags: sitecore, page-editor

In my content tree, I have "Folder" items that have no presentation, but have all the insert options on them. How would you be able to use the "Insert Page" button in the ribbon to insert a new content item in the right part of the tree?

For Example:

I have my home page Content(Folder)/Home.item 
All of my insert options are on Content(Folder), how do I add a new Home.item type without nesting it under Home.item?

Comment: From what I know you cannot add sibling item to current item in page editor out of the box.

Comment: @MarekMusielak You can use the `Insert Page` option from the Ribbon: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/creating%20and%20editing%20items/create%20an%20item%20in%20the%20experience%20editor

Comment: @jammykam from what I understood, author wants to add a sibling to current page in Experience Editor, not a child page. I don't think there is an option to do that but I might be wrong ;)

Comment: @MarekMusielak Yes, sorry misunderstood you. But you are right, you have to go up the tree and add it as a child.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to use the `Insert Page` button, the item you are inserting under must have Presentation defined. It doesn't need to have components added, and I've worked round this before by simply define a "blank" layout and setting it on those items. Maybe create yourself a new template (inheriting from Folder) and then set Layout on that. But, this is a workaround at best. You can only "Insert Page" below the current page you are on, so you would essentially have to navigate to a blank page in order to create the sibling.

From what you have stated, it sounds like you may want to re-think where your `Insert Options` have been set and your content structure, i.e. why would you want create another `Home` item? Creating so will require set-up of another `<site>` and related config. You probably also want to separate those sites out with other settings, there is some good example of [multi-site structure in this blog post](http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2009/10/how-to-multisite-in-sitecore.aspx). If you go down this route look into using [Branch Templates](http://www.geekhive.com/buzz/post/2015/2/how-to-create-branch-templates-in-sitecore-cms). But, difficult to know what you are doing without context...